# Table with multiple foreign keys linking to the same primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been having a lot of difficultly recently getting the query result I want with my MySQL database - at the moment I'm not sure if the problem is with the database or the actual query.

Basically its a football player database with these tables:

```
(player): player_id (primary), playerName
(match): match_id (primary), playerID1, playerID2, playerID3, etc..
```

I want to query the database so that I am returned with the attributes in the match database, but the names of the players are returned rather than their ID's.

I can get it to work for one player, but not the others.  Here's the code:

```
SELECT p.Name 
FROM `match` m
inner join `player` p on p.player_id=m.playerID1
```

But when I add the second player, `p.Name` is already mapped to `playerID1` so it won't work.

I suspect its the database which isn't designed very well, but any recommendations are welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That database design is causing your headaches. You should have decomposed the relationship between `Match` and `Player` by adding a `MatchPlayer` table that has both a `MatchID` and a `PlayerID`, thus allowing as many players as possible to be linked to a `Match`, without having to have a field for each one.

For your query though, you'll have to do something like this:

```
SELECT p.Name 
FROM `match` m
INNER JOIN `player` p 
    ON p.player_id IN (m.playerID1, m.playerID2, m.playerID3) //etc
```

**Demo SQLFiddle [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3c6c/1)**

Comment: how p.Name will identify which player is it? dont we need to join all players i.e player1,2,3 seperately in this case?

Comment: It won't identify which field it matches on, but that wasn't the question :)

Comment: IMO p.player will map 1st col i.e player1

Comment: There is only one playerId in the Player table, read the question again.

Comment: he need to return all player1, player2's corresponsding name how its possible without joining them all :)

Comment: @timus2001 hehe no problems. I had to double check myself to make *extra sure* :). Thanks!

Comment: Thats fantastic, thanks a lot.  I also have a column in the match table called scorer, which once again lists the ID of the player who scored.  Is there any way of returning the name of the scorer, or it is impossible as I'm already "selecting" the name of the player for another reason (as in i'd like to return the scorer's name in a new column).  Thanks a lot for your great help

Comment: Do you want to know all the players in the match **AND** the scorers? Or just the scorers?

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me.  That's right, all the players and all the scorers.

Comment: @user1416876 No problems, ask another question and send me the link here and I'll have a go at it for you :)

Comment: Its here, thanks a lot - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755834/sql-table-with-multiple-foreign-keys-linking-to-the-same-primary-2

Comment: @user1416876 Ah cool, think I got it working in my fiddle, I answered there :)