# Table with multiple foreign keys linking to the same primary (2)

Tags: sql

Just to expand on my previous issue - I have two tables in my database and I'll like to extract certain information.  Tables below:

```
   (player): player_id (primary), playerName
    (match): match_id (primary), playerID1, playerID2, playerID3, scorer etc..
```

You provided me with the following code to obtain the names of the players:

```
SELECT p.Name 
FROM `match` m
INNER JOIN `player` p 
    ON p.player_id IN (m.playerID1, m.playerID2, m.playerID3) //etc
```

Works beautifully thanks - there's just two adjustments I'd like to make:

1. I'd like to return the name of the scorer as well as the player names.  Since m.scorer is an ID, how do I map it to the p.Name attribute if p.Name is already being mapped to m.playerID?
2. The above query returns the names of all the players.  I will soon be adding a search feature where you search for all matches for a certain player.  Is there anyway of excluding that player from the results (seeing as we already know this player was in the match as he was searched for).  So pretty much return all matches, and fellow players for a certain player, but exclude the actual searched player from the results. Sorry if this is unclear, let me know and I'll expand on it.

Comment: The table is dead wrong (which is why you need to fiddle). The `match` table should not have a list of `player_ds` as a list of columns, that breaks 2NF.  That will result in masses of problems in future, even if you have this one problem "fixed".  You should have a `match_player (match_id, player_id, score)` with PK `(match_id, player_id)`. That eliminates all problems, and the code required for **any** query will be simple. "Multiple PKs referencing one parent" is a different issue, and not a problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like the following (assuming field names). It will show you the name of the player, the matchId of the match it was and whether they scored in that match or not :).

```
SELECT p.Name as 'Player Name', m.matchId as 'Match Id',
CASE s.scorerId WHEN ISNULL(S.SCORERID,0) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END as 'Scored?',
s.name as 'Scorer Name' --as requested from comment
FROM match m
INNER JOIN player p ON p.player_id IN (m.playerID1, m.playerID2, m.playerID3)
LEFT JOIN scorer s ON s.matchId = m.matchId
    AND s.player_id IN (m.playerID1, m.playerID2, m.playerID3)
```

See this SQLFiddle [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35fb2/1)

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for the great code, i didnt consider making a new table for the scorer.  Is there a way of manipulating the code so that I am returned the scorers name in the scorer column?  I know here it looks silly to get the name, then the scorers name again but it will make sense when I apply some php code to it later on.  Thanks again!

Comment: No problems! Check my edit, I've added `s.nams as 'Scorer Name'` onto the query :).

Comment: Hi!  The table 'scorer' doesn't have a name column - do I need to add it?  Was hoping i could link it from playerName so I don't have the same data stored twice.

Comment: Hmm well it seems redundant to be adding it again, can you not just use the player name? In PHP you can manipulate it how you want, but you only need to return it from the database once :)